# SAPUI5 Icons change of Size and Color

Tags: javascript, css, icons, size, sapui5

I am curious to find out if there is a way, to find out how to change an SAPUI5 Icon size, so it can fullfill certain criterias and color.

[image: Image of Buttons with Icons]

As you can see, the second and third Buttons do have the same size, meanwhile the first one is smaller.

How can i influence the size of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by giving the custom `class` - `increaseFont` to the specific button and override the `font-size` and `color` property.

**View.xml**

```
<FlexBox
    alignItems="Center"
    justifyContent="Start">
    <items>
        <Button enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://process" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd increaseFont"/>             
        <Button enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://open-command-field" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"/>
        <Button enabled="true" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" />              
    </items>
</FlexBox>
```

**CSS**

```
.sapMBtn.increaseFont .sapMBtnIcon {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: red;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Note: All the icons will have the same size. As there are multiple right arrows thats why it look like smaller.